# Can't import pyperclip after installation of pip3 in Debian Linux

Tags: python, linux, arm, debian, pyperclip

I've installed pip in Debian Linux (I'm using an ARM Chromebook with the Linux beta)

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

which returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (18.1-5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

However in IDLE if I try to import pyperclip, I get:

```py
>>> import pyperclip

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>

    import pyperclip

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

Any idea what's going wrong here or how I can investigate?

If I run sys.path in my IDLE Python Shell and in the command line I seem to get the same results:

IDLE:
['', '/home/test', '/usr/bin', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Command Line:
test@penguin:~$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import sys
> > >       sys.path
> > >       ['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Comment: You have to install the python module using pip3 command. For example "sudo pip3 install pyperclip"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have to install pyperclip before you can use it, because it is not part of the [python3-pip](https://packages.debian.org/buster/all/python3-pip/filelist) package. [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) is an installer which allows you to install python packages like pyperclip.

```sh
sudo pip3 install pyperclip
```

After the successful installation you can use it with python:

```py
In [1]: import pyperclip

In [2]: pyperclip.__path__
Out[2]: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyperclip']
```

Comment: Fantastic! That's all I needed. Thanks for your help. First time doing this stuff and I guess I've missed something a bit obvious.

Answer (score 1):

please check which version of Python are you launching with IDLE. 
alternatively you can check by launching `python3` and then trying `import pyperclip`. If you receive no error there you should see how to launch IDLE for Python3.
I run Xubuntu and by me in the menu I have 2 IDLE entries: one for the default python and one running on python3.7... I always have to be careful which version I am launching...

Comment: Thanks - that's smart, I've opened the command line and Python3, but I get the same result as in IDLE:
>>> import pyperclip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'